# sql: How to get related data from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have kind of a newby question, please help

I have two tables:

```
users (id, username)
```

and

```
follows (follow, follower)
```

`follow` is person who is followed, `follower` - person who followed `follow`. Both `follow` and `follower` are ids from `users` table.

I need to find all usernames of people who are followed by me, and also to get the status if they are following me. And vise versa.

The most problematic for me is how to get if they (me) are following me back.

I am writing something like:

```
select users.id, users.username, f.follow from users 
left join follows f on f.follow = users.id where f.follower = 78;
```

and it gives me all users I am following but without information if they are following me back..

====

Update:

The query provided FuzzyTree works for me. But actually I have a related issue. What if I want to get all followers of user 78 for example, and to have follow button for all of them who are not followed by me (user 71)

Comment: Although upvoted, my answer was wrong. I have deleted it.

Comment: If @Fuzzy answer is correct for the issued question then accept it. Do not change the question and demand new or modified answers. Create another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select users.id, users.username, f2.follow also_follows_follower
from users 
join follows f on f.follow = users.id 
left join follows f2 on f2.follower = users.id and f2.follow = f.follower
where f.follower = 78;
```

also_follows_follower will be null if they don't follow the follower

if you want to check another user just add another left join

```
select users.id, users.username, 
f2.follow also_follows_follower, f3.follow also_follows_me
from users 
join follows f on f.follow = users.id 
left join follows f2 on f2.follower = users.id and f2.follow = f.follower
left join follows f3 on f3.follower = users.id and f3.follow = 71
where f.follower = 78;
```

Comment: just one small question. What if I am not user 78. E.g. I am looking on followers of user 78 and whant to check whom of them are followed by me?

Comment: @OlegTarasenko either change `f2.follow = 71` or add another left join if you need values for both

Answer (score 3):

```
select users.id, users.username, f.follow, 
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 from follows f1 where f1.follow=78 and f1.follower=f.follow)
THEN 'Following ME' else 'Not' END as Folovingme
from users 
left join follows f on f.follow = users.id 
where f.follower = 78;
```